# Cant find facebook button using django-socialauth

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-socialauth

i want to Login via twitter, facebook, openid, yahoo, google using a single app.

so i choose django-socialauth

i read this artile : [django-socialauth-login-via-twitter-facebook-openid-yahoo-google/](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/08/django-socialauth-login-via-twitter-facebook-openid-yahoo-google/)

but when i download the code , and run it , i cant find the facebook button ,

what can i do  ?

thanks

this is my demo image:

[image]

and this is the  author's demo  :[here](http://uswaretech.com/forum/login/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I had to slightly tweak their view code in order to get this to work. Looking in *socialauth.views*, you see that we're getting the attribute **FACEBOOK_APP_ID** from our settings file. This is good.

Looking at the **socialauth/login_page.html** template, there's a section:

```
{% if FACEBOOK_APP_ID %}
  <div id="facebook">
    <p><fb:login-button perms="{{ login_button_perms }}"></fb:login-button></p>
  </div>      
{% endif %}
```

Now, this appears to be accessing the variable FACEBOOK_APP_ID. Of course, we get that attribute in *socialauth.views*. However, we've got one problem. We never expose the variable to the template (which has to be done manually, remember?). So, we replace the **old** login_page view:

```
def login_page(request):
  return render_to_response('socialauth/login_page.html', 
                          {'next': request.GET.get('next', LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)}, 
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

with:

```
def login_page(request):
  return render_to_response('socialauth/login_page.html', {
    'next': request.GET.get('next', LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL),
    'FACEBOOK_APP_ID': FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  },
  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Note that the only difference is in the line 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID': FACEBOOK_APP_ID.